# create button to clear all forms and array inside divs

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to create a button to clear all form fields and a array inside a Divs box i have script that will clear just the array or a script that will clear the form fields i cant seem to find any thing to help me clear all with one button i will post the 2 scripts below
the top one will clear the divs only the bottom one will clear the forms

```
function clearForms()
 { 
            number=[]
            number.splice(0); 
            var x = document.getElementById("box");  
            x.innerHTML = ""; 
            x.innerHTML = number.join('<br/>');   
        } 

 function clearForms()
{    
 var x, y, z, type = null; 
for (x = 0; x < document.forms.length; x++)
 {     
 for (y = 0; y < document.forms[x].elements.length; y++) {   
  type = document.forms[x].elements[y].type;   
      ('form='+x+' element='+y+' type='+type); 
 switch (type)
 {           
 case 'text':           
 case 'textarea':            
case 'password':           
 //case "hidden":                
document.forms[x].elements[y].value = '';               
 break;           
 case 'radio':           
 case 'checkbox':                
document.forms[x].elements[y].checked = '';               
 break;            
case 'select-one':                
document.forms[x].elements[y].options[0].selected = true;               
 break;           
 case 'select-multiple':              
  for (z = 0; z < document.forms[x].elements[y].options.length; z++)
 {                   
 document.forms[x].elements[y].options[z].selected = false;              
  }                
break;           
 }
 // end switch      
  } 
// end for y 
   } 
// end for x
}
```

Comment: div dont have type tag, so we cant workout inside second function switch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't figure out what means to clear an array inside a DIV, but to reset all your forms from page, try this:

```
function clearForms() {
  for (x = 0; x < document.forms.length; x++)
    document.forms[x].reset();
}
```

This function will revert all forms values to their default values.

Comment: thanks this clears all my forms but i have a arry "var number = [];" that i need it to reset as well :)

Comment: Thanks if i place my top script with your 1 under it works thanks